# Multiple WSDL Urls generate source with maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
<!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>firstrun</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>my.package.osb.services.wsdl1</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://x.x.x.x:8002/wsdl1?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>secondrun</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
            <generatePackage>my.package.osb.services.wsdl2</generatePackage>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <url>http://x.x.x.x:8002/wsdl2?wsdl</url>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<!-- end::wsdl[] -->
```

My understanding is that the above should generate the POJOs described in the two URLS in two different packages.

I don't understand why it does not work. The error I am getting after `mvn jaxb2:generate` is `No schemas to compile. Skipping XJC execution.`

Can one please provide a complete solution on how to do this properly but with **WSDL urls**?

Comment: it would help commenting on the downvote to avoid the same bad question in the future.

Comment: Post the full `mvn -X clean install`. Otherwise the config looks fine. Here's one of the test projects. Maybe try to upgrade to `0.13.1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `mvn jaxb2:generate` maven doesn't use the `configuration` inside the execution.

You have already declared a `phase` on which your executions should be bound, so just run `mvn generate-sources`.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag says:

> **Note:** Configurations inside the `<executions>` tag differ from those that are outside `<executions>` in that they cannot be used from a direct command line invocation. Instead they are only applied when the lifecycle phase they are bound to are invoked. Alternatively, if you move a configuration section outside of the executions section, it will apply globally to all invocations of the plugin.

Comment: When I give `mvn generate-sources` nothing happens.

Comment: This would be another problem... If the executions are bound to the lifecycle phase then they should be executed by maven. any logs?

Comment: Nothing helpful. I resorted to another plugin and it worked. The error might have been that I had the whole plugin decleration in the plugin manager. Because that was what it took for the other plugin to work. I will test with the above configuration and update the question